# How many zombie and orphan processes are created by these fork()

Tags: c, operating-system, fork

```
if (fork() == 0) for(;;) sleep(1);
else exit(0);
```

I know what is zombie and orphan process but dont know how to anwser this question.  Please explain me how many zombie and orphan processes can be generated by executing this code . Thanks!

Comment: see the manpage of the `fork()` syscall, then.

Comment: Zombies are only generated on exiting children whos parents do not wait on them.

Answer (score 2):

There is only one `fork`, so there is only 1 child. The parent exits without `wait`ing for a child process. The child enter in an endless loop and shortly thereafter the parent is exists, so it becomes an orphaned process. So: 0 zombies, 1 orphaned.

However if the `fork` fails, then there is no child process at all and the parent exists anyway.